# How to test a CSV file and how to find difference between two CSV files

Tags: csv, testing, comparison, manual-testing

I would like to know if is there any way of testing a CSV file before importing to database?

I have a huge CSV file with multiple columns and each column has different datatype and size. How can I test that the data appearing in generated CSV file is in accordance to the size of each column?

Also, Is there any way to compare to similar CSV File and printing the difference between those two files? 
I tried CSV Diff on Windows7 and it's not working.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvdiff/

tabletext comparator(http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_comparison.html) looks like a viable option but failing to compare very huge files

Any programming option or script that can help me in dealing with my current concern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help. There is a tool called Total commander (it is paid after one month so you can try). It has an option to compare content of two files.